# Is there HDR monitor support in Ubuntu

Tags: hardware, monitor, wayland

More monitors have the HDR (high dynamic range) functionality. Does Ubuntu (Linux) support this, too?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update 2024 03** [OBS Studio 30.1](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/releases) enabled HDR for HEVC over RTMP.

**Update 2024 01** **Valve**: [Proton 8.0-5 brings more **HDR** gaming to Linux / Steam Deck plus lots of fixes (GamingOnLinux)](https://www.gamingonlinux.com/2024/01/proton-80-5-brings-more-hdr-gaming-to-linux-steam-deck-plus-lots-of-fixes/). Article's **discussion** gives more details.
An overview from [**Arch Wiki** on HDR monitor support](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HDR_monitor_support).

**Update 2023 07** The **work** for HDR support on Linux is **ongoing** and it looks like it will **take some more years** till we can enjoy it [according to this statement on wiki.gnome.org](https://wiki.gnome.org/Hackfests/ShellDisplayNext2023):"The main goal is to plan the next 1-2 years of work and direction in how to support HDR, VRR and other new GPU and graphics technologies that are exposed to the final user through Mutter and Shell."
**Red Hat's HDR Hackfest in April 2023** To Further Advance HDR Support On The Linux Desktop [Sounds Like It Was A **Success**](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Red-Hat-HDR-Hackfest-Recap).
**Several companies** (Red Hat, KDE, System76, AMD, Igalia, Collabora, Canonical, and others. NVIDIA, Intel, and Google) were involved (partially remotely). Earlier 2023 Valve helped that [HDR Beginning To Work For Linux Gaming](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Valve-HDR-Linux-Gaming-Begins).

As far as I found out (**2021 12**), there is **no HDR support for Ubuntu yet**, [you can only use SDR](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/i8z75f/comment/g1bms1q/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). But the developers are working on this (see [Red Hat Is Hiring So Linux Can Finally Have Good HDR Display Support](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Red-Hat-Hiring-For-Linux-HDR)):
"While there has been various HDR enablement efforts for years, it hasn't crossed the finish line due to Wayland vs. X.Org and the multiple Wayland compositors, the various GPU driver differences, and similar challenges. Plus many open-source developers not having any HDR displays due to the associated cost."

Comment: Has something changed yet?

Comment: @france1 Good question! I have not seen anything. The recent Red Hat release notes only mentioned a HDR error: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/pdf/8.6_release_notes/red_hat_enterprise_linux-8-8.6_release_notes-en-us.pdf. - Anybody else heard some news?

Comment: There was some news about HDR in gaming https://www.phoronix.com/news/Valve-HDR-Linux-Gaming-Begins